# How do I associate test methods to test cases?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I am unable to associate test methods to test cases in the Test Explorer (the "Associate to Test Case" option is greyed out), or via MTM, or the VSTS website.  I simply cannot find a way to associate tests to the test cases for automated testing.

I am using .NET core app 1.1, ASP.NET using MSTest (though I have tried Xunit as well, to no avail).  Even a basic test case that always passes cannot be associated.

In MTM, I have created a test plan that has the Automation Status set to "Plan".

In VSTS, I have a project using a Git repository, in which I have a CI build created that successfully discovers, runs and reports the tests.

I cannot find where to associate these specific tests to test runs.  How may I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to these steps to associate test method to test case:

1. Install MTM 2017 (Run VS 2017 install app (vs_Enterprise.exe)>Modify)

[image]

2. Open VS 2017>Tools>Options>Work Items>General> Select Visual Studio (Compatibility mode) for Open work items in:

[image]

3. Open your test project in VS 2017 and build
4. Open Team explorer and connect to your team project
5. Type test case id in Search Work items box> Press enter to open test case
6. Select Associated Automation tab and click …
7. Select a test method > OK
8. Save test case work item

Another way is that you can associate the test method with test case through Update a field REST API.

For example:

`PATCH https://[account].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/[testcaseid]?api-version=1.0`

Content-Type: `application/json-patch+json`

Body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestName",
    "value": "[namespace.classname.methodname (e.g. UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod2)]"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestStorage",
    "value": "[assembly name(e.g. unittestproject1.dll)"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestId",
    "value": "[guid id]"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestType",
    "value": "Unit Test"
  },
   {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus",
    "value": "Automated"
  }
]
```

The AutomatedTestId is a Guid value, so you can generate a new Guid by using this C# code:

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
string s = g.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you starain!

Unfortunately, I have tried updating the associated automation inside VS, but it doesn't show any test methods despite them being visible in the test explorer.  Is there anything special I need to set on them for them to be visible?

Comment: @IanZimmérman AFAIK, Visual Studio will only recognize MSTest v1 tests. The REST API method does work, however.

Comment: Where in xUnit file do I need to specify the same GUID as in `Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestId` field for linking to work?

Answer (score 0):

Check this extension that **I have created** https://github.com/JanuszNowak/janono.ado.testcase.associate.cli . It allows associating in automatic manner. So if yours selenium test are using xunit, nunit or mstest you can **associate them automatically**.

Code sample:

```
namespace ExampleTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    [janono.ado.testcase.associate.Organization("janono-pub")]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [janono.ado.testcase.associate.TestCase(5)] //<---
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            //yours test method content
            //...
            //
        }
    }
}
```