# How to associate a test result posted to VSTS with a testcase residing in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

We have an automation test framework written in Java.

At present, I can post a new test run to VSTS.

I can then post a new test result to the test run, eg:

```
{'testCaseTitle':'vstsPostTest',
'automatedTestName':'myAutomatedTestName',
'outcome':'Passed',
'errorMessage':'successfully completed vstsPostTest'}
```

However, when viewing the test result entry in VSTS, the testCaseTitle always seems to be overridden with value: 'myTestCaseTitle'.

Thinking this may be because I haven't associated the posted result with a testcase that resides in VSTS, I have added the testCase id parameter, and specified the ID of a random existing testCase in VSTS, eg,

```
{'testCaseTitle':'is title now necessary?',
'testCase'{'id':283},
'automatedTestName':'myAutomatedTestName',
'outcome':'Passed',
'errorMessage':'successfully completed vstsPostTest'}
```

My posted result still has the generic title 'myTestCaseTitle' - and I have seen nothing yet in VSTS which illustrates a link between the posted result and the specified testcase which resides in VSTS.

What else is necessary to:

a) Ensure that a posted result uses the specified testCaseTitle value (or receives it from the ID of the associated testCase)

b) See that either a testCase or story in VSTS is flagged as failing/passed, based on the latest testrun results.  (ie, identify where stories are failing as a result of automated regression testing)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to Starains help.   As commented: I ended up carefully following this MS post: social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/… To others reading: after a VSTS test plan, suite, case is created: post a new test run (specify plan ID), then post a new test result (specify testPoint ID, outcome, etc) then get the testResult ID and update that test result to state: Completed. This is the minimum to affect the outcome of a test case in VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify test point ID:

POST: `https://[team project url]/_apis/test/runs/[test run id]/results?api-version=3.0-preview`

```
[
  {
    "testPoint":{
        "id":XX
    },
    "priority": 1,
    "outcome": "Passed"
  }
]
```

You can get test point id by using [Test points REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/points)

Comment: Thanks Starain -- I obtained test point id 4 eg _apis/test/Plans/265/Suites/266/Points/4        But when running against your json, am  told 'AutomatedTestName must be specified for automated test runs when neither TestPointId nor TestCaseId has been specified.'    So I extended json to provide:   testCaseTitle, testCaseID, automatedTestName, testPoint ID, Priority, Outcome, Error Message.     Then 'completed' the testRun.   There still seems to have been no link made between testcase and result (within latest testrun). I notice "automated":false in the record for url ... /Points/4 - An issue?

Comment: Do you associate test to test case? If not, refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581836/how-do-i-associate-test-methods-to-test-cases) to associate test to test case through REST API.

Comment: Thanks Starain. I ended up carefully following this MS post:   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d822f877-cbb1-4424-9d43-c7761f36337d/tfs-2015-rest-api-how-to-create-automated-test-run-for-test-point?forum=TFService    To others reading: after a VSTS test plan, suite, case is created: post a new test run (specify plan ID), then post a new test result (specify testPoint ID, outcome, etc) then get the testResult ID and update that test result to state: Completed.   This is the minimum to affect the outcome of a test case in VSTS.

Comment: I wasn't able to post a result only once - which would have been nice.  Ie, create new test run, then post a result one time, containing outcome and state: completed.     Doing this left the testCase in VSTS with outcome of: In Progress.   I had to patch the result with state: Completed, to fully affect the testCase outcome in VSTS.