# How to create test cases in VSTS in a programmatic manner?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a unit test project for client side (angular) application written using jasmine framework.

In C# unit test projects, there is a possibility to link each test method with a test case in visual studio test explorer.

Since it's not possible to achieve the same for test methods/suites in unit test project for client side (angular) application which is written using jasmine framework, I was looking at the possibility of creating a tool to create test cases in VSTS by programming. And to map each client side unit test method to a test case in VSTS.

Can anyone help me with the API's and idea on how this can be done?

Comment: Perhaps T4 templates could help? We use them to dynamically create unit and integration tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST API for Test Management is pretty extensive and documented clearly over at the VSTS documentation website.

The API is separated into two parts:

1. The [Test Management API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/overview) for creating Test Plans and Test Suites and to link items together.
2. The [Work Item API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items) for creating and updating Test Cases (which are essentially just a work item).

Answer (score 2):

Using REST API to do it:

Patch `https://[account].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/[testcaseid]?api-version=1.0`

Content-Type: `application/json-patch+json`

Body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestName",
    "value": "[namespace.classname.methodname (e.g. UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod2)]"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestStorage",
    "value": "[assembly name(e.g. unittestproject1.dll)"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestId",
    "value": "[guid id]"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestType",
    "value": "Unit Test"
  },
   {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus",
    "value": "Automated"
  }
]
```

The AutomatedTestId is a Guid value, so you can generate a new Guid by using this C# code:

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
string s = g.ToString();
```

Refer to [How do I associate test methods to test cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581836/how-do-i-associate-test-methods-to-test-cases)

Comment: Small comment to say that this worked for me, but was missing the following because it was mandatory to add:
`{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "Title of the work item"
  }`