# VSTest-Task not running .NET Core 2.1 xUnit-Tests from Test-plan

Tags: azure-devops, xunit, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, vstest, .net-core-2.1

I'm trying to create a release pipeline in VSTS that runs my xUnit-tests as specified in a `Test Plan`.

Long story short: I can't get it to work.

**What I'm using:**

- *Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS)*
- *Visual Studio Test task (v2.*)*
- *Test project targeting .NET Core 2.1*
- *xunit 2.4 with xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.4*

In Azure DevOps I defined a `Test Plan` that contains a `Test Suite` which contains a `Test` that has an `Associated Automation` which points to my xUnit test.
I had to use the REST API to link the test code to the `Test` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48944726/750065).

I can select that `Test` in the visual designer for the VSTest task.

When I run the release pipeline the VSTest task fails with the following error message:

`DiscoveryMessage : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find tests for D:\a\r1\a\Foo.Tests.dll. Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" and framework version settings are appropriate. Rerun with /diag option to diagnose further.`

The path to the Foo.Tests.dll is correct, all required files are copied as well.

- I explicitly specified the framework version in a `.runsettings` file (as the option `Other console options` doesn't work when using the `Test plan` option).
- Specified the `path to custom test adapters`
- used `Visual Studio 2017` and `Installed by Tools Installer` options
- Added a `.NET Core Tool installer` to install the correct .NET Core SDK
- ...and any other combination of settings I could think of.

The error message is still the same.

Any ideas what I might be missing? Your help would be *greatly* appreciated at this point!

Comment: Did you reference the ""Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" in your project? Is it possible to share a project sample for us to check the issue?

Answer (score 2):

After several more hours we stumbled across a web page that stated that you don't have to copy the binaries of your test project as input for the VSTest task but PUBLISH it instead. That never came to mind as `vstest.console.exe` runs smoothly when you point it at the binaries on a local machine.

---

**UPDATE:** We had to add a [Publish Artifact task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) at the end of our Build Pipeline and make the Release Pipeline pick up the published artifact.

[image]

Comment: do you have a link to the site?

Comment: @MrShoubs Sorry I couldn't find it again.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I'm running into this same issue but am not sure the steps you took to resolve.

Comment: I'm also seeing a similar thing; in this case I already had a Publish Artifacts step.