# Test case linked to automated test (.NET Core, Jasmine, Jest, Xamarin)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

we are working on a system that consists of web and mobile apps. The web app is a SPA and the mobile app is developed with Xamarin. Both consume services written in .NET Core.

We use other unit test frameworks (Jasmine, JUnit, Jest,. Net coree) for unit testing and we need to link some of those test so certain test case in VSTS for regulatory and compliance purposes.

Is there any way we can link this unit tests to our test cases? or Any suggestion how we can document this unit tests with work items in VSTS using these frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can associate automated tested with test cases.

You can associate all testes (Jasmine, JUnit, Jest,. Net core) with test cases by REST API:

```
PATCH https://[account].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/[testcaseid]?api-version=1.0
```

Content-Type: `application/json-patch+json`

Body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestName",
    "value": "[namespace.classname.methodname (e.g. UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod2)]"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestStorage",
    "value": "[assembly name(e.g. unittestproject1.dll)"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestId",
    "value": "[guid id]"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestType",
    "value": "Unit Test"
  },
   {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus",
    "value": "Automated"
  }
]
```

More details, you can refer starain's answer in the post [How do I associate test methods to test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581836/how-do-i-associate-test-methods-to-test-cases).

Comment: What about the test results?. Are these associated with the test cases when the automated tests are executed?

Comment: @grifoxx So you can associate with test cases by using REST API.