# Cannot Associate Test Case in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, tfs, azure-devops

I have a standard MSTest unit test in a unit test C# project file.  The project is running .NET Framework 4.7.2, and has version 1.3.2 of the MSTest adapter and framework installed.  I am running Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.7.6, and have a VSTS workspace with some random manually-created test cases in it.

When I right-click on my unit test in the Test Explorer, and select "Associate to Test Case", I am able to enter the test case ID, add the association, and click "Save".  Upon save, I get an error message, below.

[image: Method not found: 'System. Threading. Tasks. Task'l <Microsoft. Team foundation. Worldte mTraclcing.WebAptModels.Worldtem> Microsoft. Teamfoundation.Workltem Tracking.WebApi.Workltem Tra ckingHttpCiientBase.UpdateWorkltemAsync (Microsoft.VisuaiStudio.SeiVices.WebApi.PatchJson.JsonPatchDocu men!, lnt32, System.Nullable'1 <Boolean>, System.Nullable'1 <Boolean >, System.Nullable'1 <Boolean>, System.Object, System.Threadi ng.Cancellation Token)'.]

I have tried to save the association using different versions of MSTest, and different .NET Framework versions for the project file, neither of which solved the issue.  I also tried running Visual Studio as an administrator, which did not work.  Has anyone else had this issue, or know of any workarounds?

Comment: Looks like a problem in Visual Studio. Have you tried a repair install?

Comment: A repair install unfortunately did not solve the issue.  I am going to try running an older version of VS2017 Enterprise, 15.6.7.  I have an open case with MS, where at least one other person was able to reproduce the issue on 15.7.6, and was able to fix it by going down one to 15.7.5.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/309413/cannot-associate-test-case-in-visual-studio.html?childToView=310107#comment-310107

Comment: Since updating to VS 2017 15.8.0, the error message is no longer displayed.  Instead, "Associate to Test Case" is disabled upon right-clicking a test in the Test Explorer.

Comment: I also have an ongoing MS community post here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/309413/cannot-associate-test-case-in-visual-studio.html?childToView=311392#comment-311392

Comment: Just confirmed that behavior is the same between version 15.8.0 and 15.8.1.

Comment: This issue is still present in VS2017 version 15.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

I test it in my side using two VS2017 versions, they all works well.

For example, I add a simple test case manually in one test plan in VSTS, and then I create a simple unit test project with .net 4.7.2 in my side using VS2017 15.7.6, I could a associate to Test Case in my side.

If possible, you could test it in your side with the following steps:

(1) Test it with other VS machines(The same VS version but not in the same machine if you have).

(2) Clean the VSTS cache. Clean and rebuild your test project in solution explorer window, test it again.

(3) Tools->Options->Work Items, select "Visual Studio(Compatibility mode)" there.

(4) If still no help, add a new test simple unit test project in your VS,  uremove the nuget packages: MSTest.TestAdapter and MSTest.TestFramework, and then add a local reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, view the result again.

[image]

**Update:**

I update my VS2017 to the 15.8.1 version, I got the same issue, that option was disable in default. It would be a real feedback.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/309413/cannot-associate-test-case-in-visual-studio.html?childToView=311392#comment-311392

Other members who get the same issue could vote it.

Comment: Since installing update 15.8.0, the "Associate to Test Case" button is grayed out for all tests.  The test projects currently have v1.3.2 of the test packages installed.

I tested with other machines, both using old and new versions of VS2017, which did not work.  Performing a Clean > Rebuild did not work.  Running the Work Items browser in compatibility mode did not work.

Comment: When I removed the MSTest NuGet packages and added a direct local reference to the QualityTools.UnitTestFramework assembly, the "Associate to Test Case" selection was no longer grayed out, but I still got the error message from the original post.  None of the suggested four steps resolved the issue.

Comment: @srsedate, The latest version really has this issue, "Associate to Test Case" is grayed out for all tests, I have reported this issue to product team from your feedback in the developer community site. But if I remove the packages and refer to the QualityTools.UnitTestFramework assembly, it works well in my side. Do you install MTM in your VS machine? Or you could add the new test case to a new test plan, and then view the result again. Other members provide other workaround like using Rest API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581836/how-do-i-associate-test-methods-to-test-cases

Comment: I have tried this on one machine with MTM installed and one without, with still the same results.

Comment: Just confirmed that behavior is the same between version 15.8.0 and 15.8.1.

Comment: @srsedate，Could you share us how you create this test project? How did you create the test case in your side? My understanding is that not all test types supported this feature. Do you create a simple test project with the default template "Unit Test Project(.NET Framework)"? As you said that the Associate to Test Case is enabled after you add the references, we would think about the test project and the test case itself. Because I test it using different VS2017 machine, they all work normally. Do you use the personal VSTS account? Does a blank test case in the test plan have this issue?

Comment: The test project was created using the normal unit test project template using .NET Framework.  Our VSTS authentication is managed using AAD.  The same behavior occurs regardless of whether or not the test case is blank, and regardless of how many test cases there are in a test plan.  We observe the same behavior on 6+ machines.

Comment: @srsedate, The latest information: MsTestV2 test case association was disabled in 15.8.x as the feature was not fully ready. It will be enabled in 15.9 preview 2.

Answer (score 0):

A work around I put together and now use exclusively instead of manual association is to supply the test case id in the test method name and automatically update the case in TFS via the rest API by adding the following PowerShell script to run on a successful build in TFS.

A GUID for each test is generated using the full namespace for the test method and needs to be added to "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestId"

This would need adjusted to your own TFS authentication methods and possibly TFS version (I'm using 2017.2) along with the type of tests you need to read in. This is supporting Coded UI and xUnit. The LoadFrom at the top can be removed if you are not using Coded UI at all.

```
param (
    [string]$Dll = $(throw "-path to test Dll is required.")    
)
Write-Warning "$Dll will be locked until this powershell session closes"
#Load for CodedUi Support
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll"))
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll"))

try {
    $tests = ([Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(($Dll)).GetTypes().GetMethods() | Where-Object { $_.GetCustomAttributes($false) | Where-Object {$_.TypeId.Name -icontains 'TestMethodAttribute' -or $_.TypeId.Name -icontains 'FactAttribute' -or $_.TypeId.Name -icontains 'SkippableFactAttribute' -or $_.TypeId.Name -icontains 'TheoryAttribute'}} | ForEach-Object { @{ Class = $_.DeclaringType.Name; Name = $_.Name; FullName = $_.DeclaringType.FullName + "."  + $_.Name; }})
}
catch {

    Write-Error "Could not load or read $dll" -ErrorAction Stop
}


foreach ($test in $tests)
{
    $sha1 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider;
    $nameHash = $sha1.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($test.FullName));
    [byte[]]$toGuid = [System.Byte[]]::CreateInstance([System.Byte],16);
    [System.Array]::Copy($nameHash, $toGuid, 16);
    $guid = [guid]::new($toGuid);
    $id = ([Regex]::Match($test.Name, "(\d+)(?!.*\d)").Value)

    try {
        if ($psversiontable.PSVersion.Major -lt 6) {
            $currentGUID = (Invoke-RestMethod "http://{instance}[/{team-project}]/_apis/wit/workitems/$($id)?api-version=3.0-preview" -Method Get -UseBasicParsing -UseDefaultCredentials).Fields.'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestId'
        }
        else {
            $currentGUID = (Invoke-RestMethod "http://{instance}[/{team-project}]/_apis/wit/workitems/$($id)?api-version=3.0-preview" -Method Get -UseBasicParsing -UseDefaultCredentials -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication).Fields.'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestId'
        }
    }
    catch {
        $currentGUID = $null;
    }

    if($currentGUID -ne $guid)
    {       
        Write-Host "Updating $id."
        [array]$hash = @{
            op = "add";
            path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestName";
            from = $null;
            value = $test.FullName;        
        },@{
            op = "add";
            path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestStorage";
            from = $null;
            value = (Split-Path $DLL -leaf);
        },@{
            op = "add";
            path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomatedTestId";
            from = $null;
            value = $guid;
        },@{
            op = "add";
            path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus";
            from = $null;
            value = "Automated";
        },@{
            op = "add";
            path = "/fields/System.Reason";
            from = $null;
            value = "Completed";
        },@{
            op = "add";
            path = "/fields/System.State";
            from = $null;
            value = "Ready";
        }

        $patch = Convertto-json $hash -Compress

        write-host $test.Name
        write-host "http://{instance}[/{team-project}]/_apis/wit/workitems/$($id)?api-version=3.0-preview"
        if ($psversiontable.PSVersion.Major -lt 6) {
            $result = Invoke-RestMethod "http://{instance}[/{team-project}]/_apis/wit/workitems/$($id)?api-version=3.0-preview" -Method Patch -UseBasicParsing -UseDefaultCredentials -Body $patch -ContentType "application/json-patch+json"
        }
        else {
            $result = Invoke-RestMethod "http://{instance}[/{team-project}]/_apis/wit/workitems/$($id)?api-version=3.0-preview" -Method Patch -UseBasicParsing -UseDefaultCredentials -Body $patch -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "No changes to $id."
    }
}
```